# Извлечение содержимого из HTML регуляркой

Tags: html, регулярные-выражения

Есть страница с кнопкой.

```
<div id="fV1Qhl" style="width:39px;height:36px;" class="z-toolbarbutton" title="Создать новый (INS)" name="ACTION_create"><div class="z-toolbarbutton-body"><div class="z-toolbarbutton-cnt"><img src="/internetbank/img.theme/fatcow/32x32/page_white_add.png" align="absmiddle"></div></div></div>
```

Как скопировать регулярным выражением только айди fV1Qhl?

Comment: Почему регуляркой? Почему бы не набросать простенький синтаксический анализатор или не воспользоваться HTML/XML парсерами?

Comment: И зачем создавать вопрос заново?

Comment: Никак, регулярки не предназначены для разбора HTML. Делайте правильно.

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас *только* эта строка, и эта строка *в точности* то:

```
/id="([\w\d]+)"/
```

Если кроме этой строки есть ещё что-то (например, "страница"), то - определиться с языком и искать для него HTML-парсер.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению не могу добавлять комментарии, ещё.

@dunduk, `\w` терм, насколько я знаю, означает букву, цифру или `_`.

```
/id="(\w+)"/
```

или
    /id="(\w{6})"/

Но если Id может содержать например `!` или `-+`, что в целом вполне возможно, то надо будет добавлять эти символы или сводить всё к `.+` или `.{6}`

Comment: "*Но если*" - я же специально оговорил **эта строка в точности**. Дофантазировать за автора вопроса дополнительные условия - это можно сколько угодно, но мне лень (раз и ему лень изложить их более точно).

Comment: Я согласен, конечно. Вас упомянул к вопросу о лишнем `\d`, в вашем предложении, с моей точки зрения :) @dunduk